# Windows Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: model-view-controller, windows-authentication

is there any way to use windows authentication in ASP.NET without needing a windows account? I need a virtual directory to be passworded using the browser authentication prompt.

Comment: Are you trying to set up a route in your RouteCollection to be secured with authentication, or are you trying to set up a virtual directory in IIS with something like Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows Authentication, you need a Windows account to authenticate against.

If you're up for the challenge, you can set your application up to use [ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx)). It'll give you way to have accounts that are application specific rather than Domain Wide.